# Checking the session value that is available or not

Tags: php, session

I wrote the following `login.php` file.

```
    <?php
session_start();    
//Check everything and if everything is correct and the username and password is correct and available
      echo "Successfully";
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
    // and etc
    ?>
```

Now if the username is `session` as the the result `$_SESSION['login_user']` value is `session` also.

and then I create `check-session.html` file and it is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method = "POST" action = "check.php">
<input type = "submit" value = "check-session">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

And then the `check.php` file is as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
echo "session is available";}
else { echo "session is not available"; }
?>
```

But the problem is when the `login` operation is successfully and now I want to know that the session is created really or not, after clicking the `check-session` button in the `check-session.html` page, I see the result from server as the follows:

```
session is not available
```

Also for more information I use `wamp` server.

Comment: you have to put `session_start()` at the top of *every* page that's going to use sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `session_start();` in the start of every page that's using sessions or is related to them in any way.

In the start of your `check.php` file

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
echo "session is available";}
else { echo "session is not available"; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by making a separate file for setting session and include that file on the starting of each logged in page.

this is c.php for checking session...

```
    <?php
include 'b.php';
if(isset($_POST['check_session']))
{  
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
        echo "session is available";
    else 
        echo "session is not available"; 
}
?>
<form method = "POST" action = "c.php"> 
<input type = "submit" name="check_session" value = "check-session">
</form>
```

a.php for login

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {  
            header("Location: c.php");
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>
    <form method = "POST" action = "a.php">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">    
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

and also make b.php simply for setting session using session_start()